# How to import raw JSON into a defined type with Date field

Tags: json, typescript, date

I'm trying to import a raw JSON data file and have it convert my date string to a date object in my type.

My type is defined as:

```
export type Client = {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    dob: Date;
}
```

And my `client.json` file contains:

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Alasdair","last_name":"Kingman","dob":"1969-07-11"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Ursulina","last_name":"Skellion","dob":"1986-01-08"}]
```

In my `client.ts` file I have the following:

```
import {Client} from "./model";
import clients_raw from "../mock-data/clients/clients.json" with {type: "json"}


const clients: Client[] = clients_raw as Client[];
```

However the `as` operator is generating an error:

```
TS2352: Conversion of type
....
Types of property dob are incompatible.
Type string is not comparable to type Date
```

Is there any way to import the field as a Date object?  Or do I need to manually create the object?  However this approach seems incredibly inefficient and will loop over the entire array every time module is loaded.

```
const clients: Client[] = clients_raw.map((client) : Client => {
    return {...client, dob: new Date(client.dob) }
});
```

There must be a more efficient approach?

Comment: Why not just use string as the type of dob in Client and only convert it when you need it to be a Day object?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not possible. You have to create the `Date` by yourself. The cast does not help. Remember, typescript transpiles into JavaScript removing all its types. You need to go with your second approach